# Xamarin binding default value in xaml

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would to set my `IsVisible` property of an object in `Xaml` by default at `false`. But when I open the page, it is visible, then the binding variable is evaluated, and if it is `false`, becomes invisible.
I want that it is not visible by default, and the if the binding variable is true, it should become visible.
I've tried to insert a default value in my binding for `IsVisible` property of my object. I've tried `FallbackValue = Hidden` or `FallbackValue = Collapsed` and more, even for `TargetNullValue`, but it doesn't works. I obtain always a `XamlParseException`.

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks.

Code (simplified):

```
 <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
       IsVisible="{Binding Path=Info.IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToStringConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"
```

Answer (score 4):

The default value for your object for `IsVisible` is always `true`. This is independent from the `Binding`. You could overwrite this value in the code behind file with something like this:

```xml
<Image x:Name="myImage" Aspect="AspectFit" WidthRequest="20" 
       HeightRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End" 
       IsVisible="{Binding PropertyNameOfYourModel}" />
```

```cs
// Somewhere in the constructor
this.myImage.IsVisible = false;

// Here the binding is set at a later time
this.BindingContext = yourModelObject;
this.myImage.SetBinding(Image.IsVisibleProperty, "PropertyNameOfYourModel");
```

Another solution could be `DataTrigger`, but I haven't tested it yet:

```
<Label Text="{Binding MyObject.Text}" IsVisible="false">
    <Label.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding MyObject.Text, Converter={StaticResource NotEmptyToBoolConverter}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

[Source](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59703/missing-fallbackvalue-in-binding)

If you can wait for [Xamarin.Forms 3.2.0](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/2742), than you will have the options `FallbackValue` and `TargetNullValue` available directly in the Xamarin Xaml.

Comment: I think you meant `<Label.Triggers>`